# Using results from CTE giving ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use the results from my first query to perform a second query

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
)
UPDATE test_username SET money_counter = money_counter + 1, total_revenue = total_revenue + cte.total_revenue
WHERE username = cte.username;
```

But I'm getting an error

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"
LINE 5:  WHERE username = cte.username
                          ^
QUERY:  WITH cte AS(
        SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
    )
    UPDATE test_username SET money_counter = money_counter + 1, total_revenue = total_revenue + cte.total_revenue
    WHERE username = cte.username
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_trigger() line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42P01
```

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is from the returned results from the query:

`SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE user_id = 1;`

[image]

And the table I'm performing the second query on:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WITH clause just *defines* a common table expression. You still need a `FROM` clause to access it. Using your query 'as is' -

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
)
UPDATE test_username
SET money_counter = money_counter + 1, 
    total_revenue = total_revenue + cte.total_revenue
FROM cte
WHERE test_username.username = cte.username;
```

Comment: That got rid of the ```missing from clause``` error. But I'm getting a ```username is ambiguous error now.``` https://i.imgur.com/BO0LTi2.png. I've tried to resolve this issue by adding a name to the update query but it doesn't quite work https://i.imgur.com/Uf0lLJQ.png. Any idea what I'm doing wrong again?

Comment: My omission. `WHERE test_username.username = cte.username;`

Comment: That fixed it, great thank you!